# Build a Parameterized SQL Statement from an array of values

Tags: python

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/902836/1914034), the correct way to build a Parameterized SQL Statement that will be safe is by using a tuple to string format the query like this:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (var1, var2, var3))
```

However, in my case the values are stored in an array where the length can vary. I'm trying to create the Parameterized SQL Statement like below, but I have a syntax error that I don't understand:

```
values = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES ({})".format(",".join(u"%s", (v,) for v in values)))

>>>SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument
```

**Expected result:**

```
"INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
```

What would be the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Are these values each going to become their own row or getting filled into an unknown number of columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you expect this to do:

```
",".join(u"%s", (v,) for v in values)
```

but the error message gives you some clue on what you're doing wrong:

> SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument

the "Generator expression" part here being `(v,) for v in values`.

What you want is obviously something like:

```
values = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
placeholders = ", ".join("%s" for _ in values) 
sql = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ({})".format(placeholders)
cursor.execute(sql, values)
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error is because of how you call `",".join(...)`. It should look like the following:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES ({})".format(",".join("%s" for v in values)), values)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a temp placeholders

**Ex:**

```
values = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
placeholders = ', '.join('?' * len(values))
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES ({0})".format(placeholders), tuple(values))
```